# Disable auto-completion of tags in Zsh for git checkout command?

Tags: git, zsh, tab-completion, zsh-completion

I have a repository with a lot of tags. How can I disable completion to it for `git checkout` command

Answer (score 2):

This could helps, put these lines to your `.zshrc` file:

```
zstyle ':completion::complete:git-checkout:argument-rest:commit-tag-refs' command "echo"
zstyle ':completion::complete:git-checkout:argument-rest:blob-tag-refs' command "echo"
```

Comment: Tried and this didn't work. I would love an answer for this too!

Comment: Have you restarted your terminal?

Comment: Yep. I did and I didn't see any impact. When I did C-x+h after "git checkout" I see following output:

`tags in context :completion::complete:git::`
    `argument-rest  (_arguments __git_zsh_main _git _git)`
    `globbed-files  (_files _default _git _git)`